# Método post HttpClient Angular 10 no Envia propiedad Autorization, solo el Get envia la cabecera de Autonticacion

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, angular5, cabeceras-http

####################################################################################

Ejmeplo del post que no funciona

```
 let headers = new HttpHeaders({
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "authorization":  this.token
 });

 return this.http.post(this.url + 'sacarFuerza', { headers: headers });
```

------------------------Esto es lo que llega al API----------------------------

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3977',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '52',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9'
}
```

con el GET si agrega Autorización en la cabecera:

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3977',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  **authorization: 'Token',**
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9'
}
```

Comment: Estas pasando  el objeto `options` en la posición equivocada. `options` es el tercer argumento del método post. El segundo argumento es el body. Y ya que estas en eso investiga como implementar un `interceptor` para agregar ahí las cabeceras y no tener que hacerlo por cada petición.

Comment: Gracias, mil gracias ya funciono..................uaaa